# Generic function for two different classes

Tags: c++, class, debugging, templates, generics

I am trying to create a generic function which takes in two objects of the same class and returns the same object

This are my two classes : `Point2D` and `Point3D`

```
class Point2D
{
 public:
           Point2D();
           Point2D(int,int);

           int getX() const;
           int getY() const;

           void setX(int);
           void setY(int);

 protected:

             int x;
             int y;
};



class Point3D:public Point2D
{
  public:   Point3D();
            Point3D(int,int,int);

            void setZ(int);

            int getZ() const;

  protected:
             int z;
};
```

For Point2D : I am trying to return a Point2D object whose X,Y coordinates is the differences between 2 Point2D objects

For Point3D : I am trying to return a Point3D object whose X,Y,Z coordinates is the differences between 2 Point3D objects

Can i create a generic function to handle both of these ??? .

Below is what i have so far but it only handles Point2D object , how do i integrate Point3D object to the generic function below

> template  T PointDiff(T pt1, T pt2)
>   {
>   T pt3;
>
> pt3.x = pt1.x - pt2.x;
>
> pt3.y = pt1.y - pt2.y;
>
> return pt3;
>   }

I was thinking of something like this but the problem is that **Point2D objects does not have Z coordinate**

> template  T PointDiff(T pt1, T pt2)
>   {
>           T pt3;
>
> pt3.x = pt1.x - pt2.x;
>
> pt3.y = pt1.y - pt2.y;
>
> pt3.z = pt1.z - pt2.z
>
> return pt3;      }

Can someone please help me out thanks

Comment: search for template specialization.  iirc (long time haven't written C++) you can have a explicit specialization for certain type param. However I just wonder why you would want to use template method here?...

Comment: haha its a homework question hence have to do it this way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can set a Diff Function for each class.

for class Point2D with that :

```
Point2d Diff(Point2D &d) {
    Point2d pt;
    pt.x = this->x - d.x;
    pt.y = this->y - d.y;
    return pt;
}
```

and for class Point3D :

```
Point3d Diff(Point3D &d) {
    Point3d pt;
    pt.x = this->x - d.x;
    pt.y = this->y - d.y;
    pt.z = this->z - d.z;
    return pt;
}
```

then, your function is write like this:

```
template T PointDiff(T pt1, T pt2) {
        return pt1.Diff(pt2);
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: **set a Diff Function for each class** , does it mean i add the Diff function to the class ??

Comment: Yes, you add the Diff function to class Point2D and Point3D.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the minus operator for each class:

```
Point2D operator-(Point2D &pt1, Point2D &pt2)
{
    Point2D ret;

    ret.x = pt1.x - pt2.x;
    ret.y = pt2.y - pt2.y;

    return ret;
}

Point3D operator-(Point3D &pt1, Point3D &pt2)
{
    Point3D ret;

    ret.x = pt1.x - pt2.x;
    ret.y = pt2.y - pt2.y;
    ret.z = pt1.z - pt2.z;

    return ret;
}
```

You also need to declare `operator-` as a friend of both the classes:

```
class Point2D
{
public:
    Point2D();
    Point2D(int,int);

    int getX() const;
    int getY() const;

    void setX(int);
    void setY(int);

    friend Point2D operator-(Point2D &pt1, Point2D &pt2);
protected:

    int x;
    int y;
};

class Point3D:public Point2D
{
public:
    Point3D();
    Point3D(int,int,int);

    void setZ(int);

    int getZ() const;

    friend Point3D operator-(Point3D &pt1, Point3D &pt2);
protected:
    int z;
};
```

You can then use this in a program just by using subtraction

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Point2D a, b, c;

    a.setX(4);
    a.setY(5);
    b.setX(2);
    b.setY(-10);

    c = a - b;

    std::cout << c.getX() << " " << c.getY() << std::endl;
}
```